# I am getting a java error message

Tags: java

I am getting an error message on my code, please help. My Error is at if(charAt.equals(alphbets[i])) {
I don't understand why it is an error the error message says "Cannot invoke equals(char) on the primitive type char"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ACSL1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Month = "January";
    int FirstInt = 0;
    int SecondInt = 0;
    int LastInt = 0;
    System.out.println(Month);
    String month[]={"January", "Feburuary", "March", "April",
                    "May","June","July","August", "September", 
                    "October", "November", "December"};
    char alphbets[]={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
                     'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    FirstInt = Month.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
        if(Month.equals(month[i])) {
            SecondInt=i+1; 
             break;
        } 
    } 
    char charAt = Month.charAt(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
    if(charAt.equals(alphbets[i])) {
            LastInt=i+1; 
             break;
        } 
    } 
}

}
```

Comment: StackOverflow questions have historical importance for future readers, please do not remove the question after it's answered.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call any methods on primitive types, of which `char` is one.  To compare for equality, you can use `==`, just like for numeric primitives.

```
if (charAt == alphbets[i])
```

This is in contrast to `String`s, on which you would use `equals`.